# What's the point of getting faster RAM if i7's are spec'd at DDR3-1066/1333?

Tags: memory, hardware-rec

Hey, I want to get some DDR3-2200 RAM, but I noticed that the i7's say "DDR3-1066/1333" for their memory type (like [here](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=52214&processor=i7-2600K&spec-codes=SR00C)). If I bought DDR3-2200 would it be any better than DDR3-1333? I also see that the latency takes more clocks on DDR3-2200 anyways, so is it really much faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only see a performance gain if you did some extreme overclocking to get it to 2200 I would just get a set of triple-channel 1600's if I were you they are good enough for normal overclocking.

Read through this to get an understanding of the subject http://www.guru3d.com/article/gskill-2200-c7-ddr3-pi-memory-review/1